# change the sequence of custom plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created 4 custom plugins in wordpress for social media login. If more than one is activated then it should always ask for option which one to choose for login with?

```
1) login with facebook
2) login with google
3) login with linkedin
4) login with 0365
```

as individual they all works fine means when admin is not logged in it redirect me to facebook for login.
When user activate more than one social login plugin that time what should I do so that user will see the option witch plugin need to choose and will also get called immediately after selection? Please Help me in this